# Typescript: Function return type that depends on value of string parameter

Tags: typescript

I'd like to write types for a JavaScript library that creates an object of functions depending on a string that is passed to it.

The function is supposed to be something like this:

```
function createResource(name: string): { /* How to write these types? */ } {
  return {
     [`create${name}`]: () => {},
     [`update${name}`]: () => {},
  }
}
```

The idea is that given a string to a function (say "todo"), the function would return an object

```
{
  createTodo: (todo: Todo) => void,
  updateTodo: (todo: Todo) => void
}
```

Comment: this might help you out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52817922/typescript-return-type-depending-on-parameter

Comment: You want the computed property `create${name}` to be inferred based `name` if I understand this right. This is not possible. You can't perform string literal type manipulations.

Comment: Relevant issues: [Microsoft/TypeScript#12754](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12754) and [Microsoft/TypeScript#13969](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13969)

Answer (score 3):

If/when [microsoft/TypeScript#40336](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336) is merged into master (hopefully for TS4.1) you will be able to use *template string types* to represent what happens when you concatenate `"create"` and `"update"` to the string passed in for `name`.  It will look kind of like this:

```
function createResource<T extends string>(name: T) {
    return {
        [`create${name}`]: () => { },
        [`update${name}`]: () => { },
    } as { [K in `${"create" | "update"}${T}`]: () => void };
}
```

which produces an output like this:

```
const resource = createResource("Todo");
/* const resource: {
    createTodo: () => void;
    updateTodo: () => void;
} */
```

Note that `` `create${name}` `` does not produce `"createTodo"` unless `name` is `"Todo"` with a capital `"T"`.  It is possible to use the `capitalize` modifier to turn `"todo"` into `"Todo"` in the type system, but your implementation would also need to change... something like:

```
const cap = (s: string) => s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.slice(1);
function createResource2<T extends string>(name: T) {
    return {
        [`create${cap(name)}`]: () => { },
        [`update${cap(name)}`]: () => { },
    } as { [K in `${"create" | "update"}${capitalize T}`]: () => void };
}

const resource2 = createResource2("todo");
/* const resource2: {
    createTodo: () => void;
    updateTodo: () => void;
} */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-pr-40336-8#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBATgUwIZTQJTQZzhBQjQB4AVRNAD2zABN9F8oUYwBzAPgAowMAWzQAuRBQCUiAN4BYAFCIlidFGJI5i5doDaAA1SZsAEmkDhAXz0BdMbykBebjMQWANAu269IAA4MsNFNzNCtbRHtEJxd3T2ULRAxmaUQdAGlEDkQ9UwAiQ0DcxAAfRFy-AOxci1MKMLtHZwA3OBgGVwBuBQsFBQgEVhUCIhI0KOR0QLxCYlJeXIo4BjhciQ7EBQB6ACpkAaghmdGxTW0C7EXlhqjm1oYurSUKwMu4a+iWtoeE7c3e+X6YEGEAwvnGvHwYlY7C4jRYADoIAALDAoACCUF4AAYJPCoHAAKq+XxoFAAYSSaEiAGoEfgADYwOYARjWClAkFgCAmRlww1maAATJRqHQ0IxmNCODx+EJROIpKdlKp1DI4l5UgZJiZpCDfLLhBJ6hE4SlYo8vPpnjq9Qa0EabO9nGaPBaEkkXOlMkgctJ8tq0EVSuV-IUarrQTAoBhGQAvMZ1R0mm6IT7tCzff6AwboI6kQXjc58vNC+b45arB47PZAg65kb5k7qnkvJZvZMfO4PbTWtCvJ2prvdRC-f5AA)

Comment: I wasn't able to find any document or description for `capitalize`. Can you give me a ref to read more about them?

Comment: The link at the top of my answer, [microsoft/TypeScript#40336](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336) has the only current documentation about template literal types, since it is a new feature which hasn't even been merged into the master branch yet.

Answer (score 0):

Just define the object with implementations (I assume you would like to replace `void` with an actual implementation or a function call):

```
const functions = {
  createTodo: (todo: Todo) => void,
  updateTodo: (todo: Todo) => void
}
```

and then your `createResource` func will look like that:

```
function createResource(name: string) {
  const createFuncName = `create${name}`
  const updateFuncName = `update${name}`
  return {
     [createFuncName]: functions[createFuncName],
     [updateFuncName]: functions[updateFuncName]
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this solves the problem. How do I programmatically create the functions object? And is it possible to get the type after creating the resource?

Comment: Ok, probably I misunderstood your goal. How would you like to implement (I mean provide the function body) those functions programatically? My solution assumes that you provide those impl "by hand" and hardcode the `functions` object.