# Typescript return type depending on object parameter

Tags: typescript

How can I properly infer the return type based on a function that has one parameter that is a union of two types?

I've tried the following with conditional types, but it does not work (see inline comment for the typescript error):

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGwCuBnKBeKByFDkoBVwIsAoUSKAcQHt4AbAQQGNgBLANzdA2wHM6TVp24gikMuWJRGAJz5IAthAB2wXgG8oFCAC5suRKiwBuKIfz64RtAB8oKpPXpQAvlHtad%20rAIYt2LlBTKD8hQNF9Wn9hIJAPBycXV1JSZhoVXCgAC3gVABN6CAAlCHhhDN4ACnh5fTkFZTUASnr5JVV1CAAPYFV8tC9ifQAiC1QRtygAflg8VCgowQCRHnQAPigNUihdqDYAMyga%20QA6HQx0TBx5lCxmrZ2959kIZFkVA1vxEigAej%20UB%202DG32IIyw%20zQKho6ngKBQbD4KngACMitoaNppFgRmEVnEfhDTk9du4IPQUNBts8Xm8kB9%20MtYqIfmRnilXEA)

```js
type Status = 'statusType'
type GoalActivity = 'goalActivityType'

type Argument = { type: 'status'; status: Status | null } | { type: 'goalActivity'; goalActivity: GoalActivity | null }

const handleReaction = (arg: Argument): Argument extends { type: "status" } ? Status : GoalActivity => {
    if (arg.type === 'status') {
        return 'statusType' // Type '"statusType"' is not assignable to type '"goalActivityType"'.
    } else {
        return 'goalActivityType'
    }
}
```

I've also tried the following using a form of function overloading for arrow functions ([as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187614/typescript-overload-arrow-functions)), but this also results in a TypeScript error and also uses "any" which loses most of the typing benefits inside the function definition:

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGwCuBnKBeKByFDkoBVwIsAoUSKAcQHt4AbAQQGNgBLANzdA2wHM6TVp24gikMuWJQAEvAB2AE3oQAShHjCa83gG9SUQ1AAU8AE58AXFF1QKEazjyosAbii5Eqa3C9oAPlDySPT0UAC+AJQ+zigGRqYW1rb2jgIMLOxcoG5Q6UJZota0GcLZIFCBwaER0dSCmSKgpOGkpMzauFAAFgrKahpa8tZySirqmuzavIlWUAogkRgAfDZQAPTrUOLQWABE+Y3lO3tYUGxo8jTA8ygobHzy8ABGKnY0dtL7nvgnWAB08UMbAAZiZzHx-vYMOhME4-FglvojCioGYIMgzDp4b9iGQUeEoBB6ChoMjUYZ0ZjsYcyqIdvijK1wkA)

```js
type Status = 'statusType'
type GoalActivity = 'goalActivityType'

type HandleReaction = {
    (arg: { type: 'status'; status: Status | null }): Status
    (arg: { type: 'goalActivity'; goalActivity: GoalActivity | null }): GoalActivity
}

const handleReaction: HandleReaction = (arg: any) => { // Type '"goalActivityType"' is not assignable to type '"statusType"'.
    if (arg.type === 'status') {
        return 'statusType'
    } else {
        return 'goalActivityType'
    }
}
```

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52817922/typescript-return-type-depending-on-parameter), but with the difference being that the function parameter is an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Issue

The first thing is you haven't used generic type for your argument that would result in `typescript` will never infer the correct type based on your input (you can imagine generic type is parameter, `tsc` requires it to calculate the result based on your input).

In short,

`const handleReaction = (arg: Argument): Argument extends { type: "status" } ? Status : GoalActivity => { // ... }`

will always return `Status | GoalActivity` as return type.

#### Solution

Of course, you have to use generic type here as your argument. I'll split your code out with inline explanation:

```js
type Status = 'statusType'
type GoalActivity = 'goalActivityType'

type StatusObj = { type: 'status'; status: Status | null };
type GoalActivityObj = { type: 'goalActivity'; goalActivity: GoalActivity | null }

type Argument = StatusObj | GoalActivityObj;

// Define returned type based on a input argument `T`
type ReturnType<T> = T extends StatusObj ? Status : GoalActivity;

// Generic type should be used here
const handleReaction = <T extends Argument>(arg: T): ReturnType<T> => {
    if (arg.type === 'status') {

        // Q: Why do we have to cast here?
        // A: Any returned type can't assign to statement of `type ReturnType<T> ...`
        // but luckily `tsc` still allows us to cast back since they are all string literal
        return 'statusType' as ReturnType<T>;

    } else {
        return 'goalActivityType' as ReturnType<T>;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, I think I understand. Too bad we need to cast the return value, but I'm assuming it's a TypeScript limitation.

Answer (score 0):

Your argument objects should have their own types. Once they do, you can use function overloading like this:

```js
type Status = { type: 'status', status: 'statusValue' };
type GoalActivity = { type: 'goalActivity', goalActivity: 'goalValue' };

function handleReaction(arg: Status): Status['status']
function handleReaction(arg: GoalActivity): GoalActivity['goalActivity']
function handleReaction(arg: Status | GoalActivity) { 
    if ('status' in arg) {
        return arg.status;
    } else {
        return arg.goalActivity;
    }
}

const a = handleReaction({ type: 'status', status: 'statusValue' })
//    ^? 'statusValue'
const b = handleReaction({ type: 'goalActivity', goalActivity: 'goalValue' })
//    ^? 'goalValue'
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGwCuBnKBeKBvKpIC4oByFBZFIgGilMVUJLNQDV4AbJCIqAXwG4AUHmgBxAPbsAggGNgASwBuc0Bmy5wEBgHMJbGfKWgqUHVNmLlIbbtYcuvQQIBmSAHbmxrqAAt4rgCZsEABKEPAergAU8ABOWoRwdCgAlAlMKADajElEALrObhE+foEhYRHRcYTiZgaWqVA1euaGIFmmzXVG+S7u8p7FAUGh4f1RsfGw6VAAPo26+hagyWoCUOtQck5Qkdnk3HJeEytYaxvnMRDIMUdxAHS05ILnPFAQbCjQp+cXV0g3UAmdw6i1azw2PAEkIE0k8pEBql8QzKozknkiOGEDEeqGMOJQ2PStk43B4yQEAHoKecAHoAfhhcOAUAARoiSsNymMMeoCMQQS1LMYBV0rPybOwSbxyVTaXSgA)