# Return type based on passed boolean argument

Tags: typescript, typeorm, typescript-generics, typescript-types

I want to write a function that executes SQL query strings where you can specify expected type(string, number, Date, Object with strings or numbers, but not functions, classes, and so far) via generics. Here my code is:

```
type Payload = Array<string | number>;
type ExpectedObj = Record<string, string | number>;
type Options = Partial<{
  onlyOne: true | false;
  columnName: string;
}>;

/**
 * Simple function created to execute SQL queries.
 * @param {String} queryString Required. Query string to execute.
 * @param {Payload} payload Optional. Pass variables into query string.
 * @param {Options} options Optional. Would you like to retrieve only the first record or only the one column?
 * @returns {T} Any object/property.
 */
export const executeQuery = async <T extends string | number | ExpectedObj>(
  queryString: string,
  payload?: Payload,
  options: Options = {},
): Promise<Options["onlyOne"] | Options["columnName"] extends true | string ? T : T[]> => {
  const entityManager: EntityManager = getManager();
  const queryResult = (await entityManager.query(queryString, payload)) as T extends string | number ? {
    [key: string]: T;
  }[] : T[];

  options.onlyOne = !options.columnName ? options.onlyOne : true; 

  // (the error occurs here)
  if (options.onlyOne && options.columnName) {
    return (queryResult[0] ? queryResult[0][options.columnName] : {}) as T;
  } else if (options.onlyOne && !options.columnName) {
    return (queryResult[0] ?? {}) as T;
  } else {
    return queryResult as T[];
  }
};
```

Examples of usage:

```
/* Returns array of objects */
await executeQuery<{
  fullname: string;
  age: number;
  birthday: string;
}>(SOMETHING_QUERY, [id]);

/* Returns the first record */
await executeQuery<{
  fullname: string;
  age: number;
  birthday: string;
}>(SOMETHING_QUERY, [id], { onlyOne: true });

/* Returns only the 'age' column from the first record found */
await executeQuery<string>(SOMETHING_QUERY, [], {
  onlyOne: true,      // can be skipped if columnName is passed
  columnName: "age",
});
```

Unfortunately, I catch the error saying in such format:
`Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'T[]'`.

And I poorly realize why. VSCode shows that `executeQuery` always returns `T[]`, but it's not what I expected. I saw examples of "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52817922/typescript-return-type-depending-on-parameter", but they do not help. All what I want is to make my function flexible.

Of course, I can just specify `Promise<T | T[]>`, but with this approach I have to point this everywhere(e.g. `const smth: string | string[] = await executeQuery<string>(...);` or cast returned type to string somewhere). Please, help. Also I would be glad if you correct my code...

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Please **reduce** the problem above to a [mcve] to help people help you.

Comment: But you're probably looking for [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads).

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I solved the problem with function overloads.