# TypeScript: return type narrowing based on boolean option argument

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a type for my function so that the return type changes based on a value passed to it. I've considered [Typescript return type depending on parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52817922/typescript-return-type-depending-on-parameter) and following that to (almost) the letter seems to work just fine.
In my project however, I must use arrow functions. Also, I'd like to avoid overloads if at all possible. Consider this signature and implementation:

```
type CreateDocumentListOptions = {
  withVersions?: boolean;
};

type CreateDocumentList = (
  options?: CreateDocumentListOptions
) => CreateDocumentListOptions["withVersions"] extends true
  ? DocumentWithVersions[]
  : Document[];

const createDocumentList: CreateDocumentList = ({
  withVersions = false
} = {}) =>
  times(
    withVersions ? createDocumentWithVersions : createDocument,
    chance.natural({ min: 1, max: 10 })
  );
```

when I call the function like this:

```
const documentList: DocumentWithVersions[] = createDocumentList({
  withVersions: true
});
```

I get a type mismatch as TS thinkgs `createDocumentList` returns a `Document[]` not the desired `DocumentWithVersions[]`. I was under the impression that using the ternary operator would be enough information for TS to understand that the return type would change based on its condition.

For the complete editable example: [image: Edit pedantic-newton-xx4sp]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are giving up on overloads, but you still want a return type that switches depending on the parameter, then you will need to use a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function returning a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html).  For example:

```
type CreateDocumentList = <B extends boolean = false>(
    options?: { withVersions?: B }
) => B extends true
    ? DocumentWithVersions[]
    : Document[];
```

Here the generic type parameter `B` is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `boolean` and [defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) to `false`.  Then, depending on whether `B` is `true` or `false`, the output is either `DocumentWithVersions[]` or `Document[]`.

---

One caveat with generic functions returning conditional types is that, inside the implementation of the function, the compiler cannot verify that what you are doing is safe.  Where `B` is an unspecified generic, the compiler *defers* evaluation of `B extends true ? ...`, meaning it can't see when any particular value matches the type.  This pain point is the subject of the open issue [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912).

```
const createDocumentListOops: CreateDocumentList = (({
    withVersions = false
} = {}) =>
    times(
        withVersions ? createDocumentWithVersions : createDocument,
        chance.natural({ min: 1, max: 10 })
    )); // error!
// Type 'Document[]' is not assignable to type 
// 'B extends true ? Required<Document>[] : Document[]'
```

Until and unless anything is done to address this, it means you will need to use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) or the like to avoid compiler errors in the implementation:

```
const createDocumentList = (({
    withVersions = false
} = {}) =>
    times(
        withVersions ? createDocumentWithVersions : createDocument,
        chance.natural({ min: 1, max: 10 })
    )) as CreateDocumentList; // okay
```

---

Now we can test that calls to `createDocumentList()` behave as you desire:

```
const documentList = createDocumentList({ withVersions: true });
// const documentWithVersionsList: Required<Document>[]

const documentList1 = createDocumentList();
// const documentList1: Document[]

const documentList2 = createDocumentList({ withVersions: false });
// const documentList2: Document[]

const documentList3 = createDocumentList({ withVersions: Math.random() < 0.5 });
// const documentList3: Document[] | Required<Document>[]
```

Looks good.  Note that `documentList3` is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of types because the `withVersions` property of the input is `boolean`, which is the union `true | false`, and the return type of `createDocumentList()` is [distributive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) over unions.  This may or may not be the behavior you want, but it looks reasonable to me.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAYQBYEMB2BjApnAZlCEOAIg1Uy2IG4BYAKFEljgG84ZQsBnOAXzwJFiUFCAAmKavXoYIaLvDLpscALyJy2ABQBKWnXowAnmBwARCBgCuILGhgA1LFC7A5a1vTje4wMQC44BShgNABzfR84Wy4uFDCsAH5A4NCI+n4AMjgAeRBgGAAeC2tbewAaEj9iAD59QxNzSxs7eHUWLx8-FJgQ8MifDhgAGywevvS6KIA3Z1c5LmS4Epb7Jxc3NABtAF19Xnq6Y1Nl5rKYAHUCpHX5+Q8AJSwARytgKCwxYrPWuukjxqID4oGBYFbnAAywAUOTAHAWHg6Ux8AHdrrdNotAgAjCAQUbofaHY44BDA0Hg1pQhQeQoAITgWAAHqC0GIeLj8Vh0B5cChhlwsDUtJ1vBA4Zilmw0TAbnNJYEGbx6Do1DU4Azmaz2ewoFYsKK4IlTqVWldZRiFrtDYFKfZdodZPJFOSwT81vKEepdLb3Y5PdsdmrDRhXXaYNSYLoAHQgFBgLRaMR+1WqdVaJFRKLRnPJ00VQ1RbpwJQUaNhN5iXTlQs+GJxBKBUvYaOC+x2bQ6Q28HR6f5Ommh7kUv0eH0m1ZtdOZroBEuaLDlyvVw1DUZNhfRlHQKtdug9x0LF3Dt35y7ogM8b06X1n81yjZe6eGnPRocg0+TlfI7yzR-yJswz9S15F0DI+wMOgB2PD9w0jHJxS4QIyRPODoTaOBExnbwZQfO4rzwflBQyREe2DH92E4LgRQoqJcJAnhjXfEc7wvf8eEA1C-RrWifGbRc0BBKwRGGDNolCQIAEZKjjJkpIABj4Pcol7Kg4AAenUxkoAIKAAEJ6E0uAABVAQAcnDXYzN8Hg0AgeAUFiYAwkE7FRnYCB2EBQytLMzUWTsHVen1I04CeV53k+b4zxqXY4FvScrP+GQjxLICz0jMcM0NejL15IiDX3UjUxqVcqJorNUTY-DQuYz9znvBj4rSrizx4yrvH46NBJgYT+TE-I0CkmSUDkuBJMUntDV7OBHKBVrJ0jQ5kqg1K80W9CPDqtCFDE3L2MCYKcAPHySzWv1GsvSNAnCt4Pi+cNYp2ftzoy9DJK29KNt2iCjOguB1shd6EvOa1IP+wGqXQgAmT6FqB3bpWqzFAj5AVjt+rSIb9SNoZB1owZS50AZx9CAGY4dg0nEbgfb8MCABZEEkGjEQ2UIXQ4EKOB5OjABWJT9D+17vpgMn8ftIMAB8wpeO6osewm6Eh+xI2jXBoAAURQMhExVmASs8Cj9ejP98PVrWdaQRMzc2Q3sKzAcuWjYYIDCMTbfcE6KO972gA)

Comment: Thank you kindly for such an in-depth answer—I ended up using `as` in my client code, but I always saw it as somewhat hacky and I'm trying to avoid it like the plague. Learning that it's actually _ok_ to use it in certain situations is really helpful. Also, I'm surprised that it's called "type assertions"—until now I'd refer to it as "type casting". Learning TypeScript is _such_ a journey!