# Multi conditional function result in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I try to implement a function which will return different types following its parameters.

Something like the function below, but more efficient (with generic and without the union type as result)

```js
type ResultType = {
  get: GetResult
  post: PostResult
  ...
}

function fetch(operation: keyof ResultType): GetResult | PostResult | ...
```

So I start with the example provided in: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html.
When I try to implement the function of the example :

```js
interface IdLabel {
  id: number /* + d'autres champs */
}
interface NameLabel {
  name: string /* + d'autres champs */
}

type NameOrId<T extends number | string> = T extends number ? IdLabel : NameLabel

function createLabel<T extends number | string>(idOrName: T): NameOrId<T> {
  if (typeof idOrName === 'number') {
    return { id: idOrName }
  } else {
    return { name: idOrName }
  }
}
```

I've got the following errors that I cannot understand:

```
Type '{ id: number; }' is not assignable to type 'NameOrId<T>'.
Type '{ name: string; }' is not assignable to type 'NameOrId<T>'.
```

What did I do wrong?

Bonus question: Is there another way in TS to manage lot of conditional cases (kind of switch) ?

Comment: Please include all code (and errors) as text rather than images.

Comment: why not a discriminated union as result?

Comment: Each returned object can be completely different, so I don't see how the discrimination union can help in this case.  There are indeed several workarounds, but I'm looking for a clean way of doing things... And I wish to understand why the simple implementation of the example of the handbook don't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: See ["Typescript define function args and return value based on arg"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76325719/15261914), and maybe also ["TypeScript: return type narrowing based on boolean option argument"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67621745/15261914)

Comment: You didn't do anything "wrong" per se; it's a missing feature in TS as discussed in [ms/TS#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912). If you want to implement a generic function that returns a conditional type you'll need type assertions or the like... or you could possibly use a helper function to encapsulate the particular assertions you're doing, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/N950jN).  If that fully addresses your question I will write up an answer explaining; otherwise, what am I missing?

Comment: Is not [ms/TS#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014) more applicable than 33912? At least for the result wanted.

Comment: And rather don't override the builtin `fetch` function...

Comment: What do you want in an answer? Why that code doesn't work, or how to solve your original problem?

Comment: This question *seems* to be about conditional types and not indexed access types, and there's no straightforward way I can see to use indexed access types since the inputs are of type `number` or `string` and not of literal types like `"number"` or `"string"`, so I'm not sure what the index would be.

Comment: Ah, yes. The Q&As I linked were about the original problem mentioned at the start of the post. It's unclear whether the OP wants a solution to that, or an explanation/solution to the error encountered when implementing the example from the docs.

Comment: Yeah I think OP should probably [edit] the question to make it clear whether or not the primary question is the "What did I do wrong?" about implementing a generic conditional returning function, or if it's about the underlying goal (and the conditional types are just a failed attempt)

Comment: Based on the OP's earlier comment, I believe he wants both... "Needs more focus"?

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answers. I apologize for the lack of clarity in my question, which in the end was made up of several interlocking questions. On the whole, your suggestions answer all 3 questions and propose solutions adapted to my initial problem, as stated in the title.

Comment: @JulienLalaut Upvote any answers you found helpful, and possibly accept (click the checkmark next to it) the one that you found best answered your question(s). :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is a solution to the original problem you stated, that of relating the return type to the input type.**

*The first example is a basic but not type-safe solution. The second is a little more complex, but has complete type-safety (as far as I can tell).*

You can use an [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) to specify the return type in terms of the input type.

Unfortunately, TypeScript does not fully support this yet. There is an open issue at [ms/TS#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014) for proper support under the name of "Dependent-Type-Like Functions". A workaround for your simple case is to [assert the type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) of the returned values.

The following code demonstrates a possible approach. I have had to give my own definitions of the missing types.

```js
type GetResult = {
  getData: string
}

type PostResult = {
  postData: string
}

type ResultType = {
  get: GetResult
  post: PostResult
}

function fn<T extends keyof ResultType>(operation: T): ResultType[T] {
  if (operation === "get") {
    return { getData: "foo" } as ResultType[T]
  } else {
    return { postData: "bar" } as ResultType[T]
  }
}

const res1 = fn("get")
//     ^? GetResult
const res2 = fn("post")
//     ^? PostResult
const res3 = fn("put") // Error: "put" is not a key of ResultType
```

[Playground of the above](https://tsplay.dev/NVR25N)

You could use a function map and define `ResultType` in terms of that. By creating a correlation between the function map and the type, this can be completely type-safe! (Thanks to @jcalz for pointing out this last part.)

Here's a possible implementation of that:

```js
type GetResult = {
  getData: string
}
type PostResult = {
  postData: string
}

const _operations = {
  get(): GetResult {
    return { getData: "foo" }
  },
  post(): PostResult {
    return { postData: "bar" }
  },
}

type ResultType = {
  [key in keyof typeof _operations]: ReturnType<(typeof _operations)[key]>
}

const operations: { [K in keyof ResultType]: () => ResultType[K] } = _operations

function fn<T extends keyof ResultType>(operation: T): ResultType[T] {
  return operations[operation]()
}
```

[Playground of above](https://tsplay.dev/wj8RYm)

`_operations` is an object that maps operation names to functions. `ResultType` is constructed from this. However, `_operations` is not at all linked to `ResultType`, as `ResultType` is defined in terms of it, not the other way around. So, `operations` is assigned the same value as `_operations`, but it has a type annotation that links it to `ResultType`. This allows TypeScript to understand the correlation between the operation name and the type and return type of the operation.

Comment: If I were doing this I'd implement an object of `ResultType` into which you index with `operation` (and you can use accessors to make it lazy and not pre-compute every possible output).  I'd go further but I still have no idea if that's what OP is really asking here

Comment: And the accessors would perform the actual work? I'd be comfortable with something like that. Personally, I would probably use a function map and define `ResultType` in terms of that, and leave the rest as before; something to the tune of [this](https://tsplay.dev/w6GaGN). I may update my answer with it as an alternative... Doesn't solve the issue of the ambiguous question, though.

Comment: For a function map you could use the technique described at [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) to avoid a type assertion, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/NBQAbw)

Comment: Great, @jcalz! No assertions! I completely forgot about that technique of using two identical variables and typing the second one in terms of the first.

Comment: High level... Congratulations and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're right: discriminated unions don't help much.

I think I've found a solution, but I don't know if you like that. Feel free to consider or reject.

The idea is based on [Indexed Access Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html).

Let's imagine a series of types, as you suggested, even a little complex. Note that I like more `type` than `interface`, but I think should work the same.

```
type TIdLabel = {
  id: number /* + d'autres champs */
}

type TNameLabel = {
  name: string /* + d'autres champs */
}

type TMixedLabel = {
  num: number
  text: string;
  flag: boolean;
}
```

At this point, just define our function, along its input and output types. I assigned each type to a specific key, as index.

```
type TResult = {
  "id": TIdLabel,
  "name": TNameLabel,
  "mixed": TMixedLabel,
}

type TProps = {
  "id": number,
  "name": string,
  "mixed": {
    a: number;
    b: number;
  },
}

function createLabel<T extends keyof TResult>(type: T, props: TProps[T]): TResult[T] {
  if (type === "id" && typeof props === "number") {
    return { id: props } as TResult[T];
  }
  else if (type === "name" && typeof props === "string") {
    return { name: props } as TResult[T];
  }
  else if (type === "mixed" && typeof props === "object" && "a" in props && "b" in props) {
    const { a, b } = props;
    return { num: a + b, text: "Hello!", flag: true } as TResult[T];
  }
  else{
    throw new Error();
  }
}
```

So far, the only "ugly" part is the discrimination of the input. That has to be at runtime and the `type` argument comes to rescue.

The usage is pretty straightforward, although you've to specify the `type` as discriminator.

```
const x1 = createLabel("id", 123);        //x1 is TIdLabel
const y1 = createLabel("name", "Betty");  //y1 is TNameLabel
const z1 = createLabel("mixed", { a: 6, b: 9 });  //z1 is TMixedLabel
//const w1 = createLabel("fail");  <-- won't compile!
```

It seems that the trick can be done even without the explicit discrimator. However, it depends on the ability to discriminate the cases against the input.

```
function createLabel2<T extends keyof TResult>(props: TProps[T]): TResult[T] {
  if (typeof props === "number") {
    return { id: props } as TResult[T];
  }
  else if (typeof props === "string") {
    return { name: props } as TResult[T];
  }
  else if (typeof props === "object" && "a" in props && "b" in props) {
    const { a, b } = props;
    return { num: a + b, text: "Hello!", flag: true } as TResult[T];
  }
  else{
    throw new Error();
  }
}

const x2 = createLabel2(123);
const y2 = createLabel2("Betty");
const z2 = createLabel2({ a: 6, b: 9 });
```

Here is the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAKgSQCYBkCGAjKAbGBeGAb2BhgEskAuGAOwFcBbLAJxgHoAqGAahiQHI0dEMygBnGAGMAFmgYQJHNsAC%20wUJFhwAcnKjosuAsVI091MSLI0A5uy68BQkeKmz5i5Wo3R4AWTIADyhUTBx8IhJaRmp6JihmKJAoQJALK1sAbiiAM2w0G2oMAHti7Cg0GmzvHy0AJXE6bBAIkxgAIgp26kRQwwAaKPazBihu%20F1RgxxB0naGIJDxuADgvpnVdXBfOAAFZmKFVqGu2MYWWY6RsfTmaxtL%20cWkcbbSNDP45mzSUgxPlg-GAqQbeHJ0GiSEBkYo0KSiNDJabYAA8cBgKWSNCQEgA1lAwMUcvAGmImiAAHwACm2UB6-RgEAOCh6%200OYgA2nAALoASh6pPJXO5kVIZGJNM0%20DwBE6LxgADIFTBaUTGcyJDLZXEWO1eaLfqIQHRmHDCOQqOr2cCYGgJHBBc1hUC1KQcGJYOKYJLfFqrnp2orlariUzrX72pY7rY9QbSEaTWbaOYrUcVLb7Y6QM6oq6MdgPeQJbTpbKFmtA0qVZo1WGjhHihgAFZQKGV5XtNCB6ypiRV9oYbtwutifVvKSwyxEW0MjA2ggjoHxqDG03TuLUNA8GAYBnJVLUdoACRw2GKAEJ2gy8gVqCI6LB03aSY0nTyXVF3VBxyBpAcAO60FAgEAKLMAczBUryH7eJIk4tIEACMESSAiSJhNgVJyleMCIQATAAzNBvwkewbBIeQ9rIMiwBwTQU5gMhBCoRU6GGFh1w4e0ABCK7gHqmSkGwbCMZREx6DRdFTgAXkx8KsfoGFYeWSwMuaHwwAAbLO1AAJzAsRZGyWJKzPDRwlSS0-5ySxiKKex7Q5GgZDYAJpAogAtB5MD-rC-AtHB8guVA57qMA4KQtCsLyXZyJ4WiGKpFA2J4gSaoOq%20lJUiOrIasK-IvmSb4im0Xo%20lAtYaqWVznAksbjgma7mhQ1Ajjaz4ZUV2bvrmn4Fp6xY1qGVURlG9z1VEy6rkm1ytVVT6ZplOakHmX5Ft6Ia9tV7SNi2bZBh0XbkMOVX9oOx29mOk0TvRLTqbO869kuMCNTNMS2tuu4qpih4ntgZ6Xte%20SFCqzAPu1i1dctwJ9R6P5-sUgE0MBMBgRBUEweolkwIEeEoWh9k4HhVL4UR2TY2AePMQTcVYbxID8dBtHwTA0lUzFbFE1S6nUNpO56QZ2RAA).

Comment: That do the stuff. Thanks.