# Conditional type depending on payload function in TS

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Is it possible to determine a type depending on a payload function ?

Example:

```
export const myFunction = (
  findAll: boolean
) => {
  const finders: { key: findAll extends true ? VueWrapper<T>[] : VueWrapper<T> } = {}
})
```

Here I want to change the `finders` type to an `Array` if `findAll` is at `true`

Comment: Can't. How would the compiler know if `myFunction(Math.random() > 0.5)` receives `true` or `false`? Just export two functions instead, e.g. `find` and `findAll`.

Comment: ok thank you I'll do that so

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript return type depending on parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52817922/typescript-return-type-depending-on-parameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible with [Conditional Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html).

```
type FindOrFindAllResult<TElement, TFindAll extends boolean>
  = TFindAll extends true
    ? TElement[]
    : TElement

const myFunction = <T, TFindAll extends boolean = boolean>(
  findAll: TFindAll
):FindOrFindAllResult<VueWrapper<T>, TFindAll> => {
  if (findAll) {
    return [] // replace with your function returning array
  }
  else {
    return null // replace with your function returning one element
  }
}


const arrayResult = myFunction(true) // arrayResult is of type VueWrapper<T>[]
const elementResult  = myFunction(false) // elementResult is of type VueWrapper<T>
```