# How to make return type depend on parameter type

Tags: typescript, type-inference, conditional-types, generic-type-parameters

i have a method like this
`public myMethod(param: MyClass | null): MyClass | null`
i want to somehow communicate, that the output is null only if the parameter is null. so if you pass in an instance of `MyClass` it will not return `null`.

what has been tried:

```
public myMethod<T extends MyClass | null>(param: T): T extends null ? null : MyClass {
  if (param === null) {
    return null;
  }

  return new MyClass(param.cnt + 1); // just an example, generally the constructor param is some value derived from the param
}
```

but that doesn't work - complains that "MyClass isn't assignable to T extendss null ? null : MyClass"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript return type depending on parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52817922/typescript-return-type-depending-on-parameter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common use case for [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads). It works by providing a number of separate signatures in addition to the implementation signature.

```
class Test {
    public myMethod(param: null): null;
    public myMethod(param: MyClass): MyClass;
    public myMethod(param: MyClass | null): MyClass | null {
      if (param === null) {
        return null;
      }

      return new MyClass(); // just an example, generally the constructor param is some value derived from the param
    }
}
```

The first two signatures are the overload signatures, they will be used to check argument types and determine the return type where you call the method. The last one is the implementation signature, it has to be compatible with the overload signatures and the function implementation but can't be called directly.

Comment: hmmm, good point. yeah overloads solve this too. i was just hoping if maybe there was a solution using the type system somehow, but maybe there is not. Thank you for the answer